# Image width different for landscape / portrait

Tags: image, width, tumblr, aspect-ratio

I have a Tumblr page where all the images have the same width

```
img.photo_img {max-width: 500px}
```

is there a way to style differently the portrait and the landscape ones
maybe working on their aspect ratio?

I would love to have:

PORTRAIT: width 500px
LANDSCAPE: width 750px

Thanks.

Comment: did you see the example in my updated answer?

Comment: Federico, I just realised there was a typo in my answer - I had a dash instead of an underscore in the css code. Try now

Comment: yay! thanks for the accept. Glad you finally got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with media queries

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
    img.photo_img{max-width:500px;}
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    img.photo_img{max-width:750px;}

}
```

view an example [here](http://www.rachelgallen.com/imageorientation.html)

Comment: I don't know why but this isn't working @rachel gallen
http://jsfiddle.net/eny89ue5/

Comment: you have to give it a default width in normal css first http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/eny89ue5/1/

Comment: alternatively you can use <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">

Comment: Linking in the stylesheets only affects iPad, iPhone, Android, Safari, and Firefox. You should use both to cover all bases, by both i mean media queries and linking in portrait and landsacpe css

Comment: I'm using Firefox for Mac but I would love of course it to work with all browsers.

Comment: I wish it works first Rachel then I can give you 100 upvotes.

Comment: @FedericoFerrari see the example in my updated answer

Comment: Yes I've seen it @RachelGallen but it's not working to me :(